# Decrement unsigned integer by 1

Tags: c

I want to decrement a variable by 1 while the variable is different from 0. Once this variable is zero, it must be back to the initial value.

For example:

if the initial value is 3, then the different values are:

```
  3 2 1 0 3 2 1 0...
```

Here is my code:

```
unsigned int i = 3;
do {
  if (i != 0)
  {
    i--;
  } 
  else
  {
    i=3;
  }      
while (1);
```

My question: Is there any elegant method which uses, for example, bitwise operators?

Comment: Btw you can just use `while(1)`.

Comment: @haccks: `unsigned char` is an integer type; the declaration `unsigned char i = 3;` is perfectly valid. What problem do you see with it?

Comment: @KeithThompson The title of the question.

Comment: @KeithThompson; It doesn't match with the title of the question.

Comment: @haccks: Ah, good point. Changing the title from "unsigned int" to "unsigned integer" would fix that. OP: Please edit your question to make it consistent.

Comment: OP, after 5 answers & 45 minutes, you do a disservice by changing the code from using `unsigned char` to `unsigned`.  Had it been originally `unsigned` the original answer by @Sam DeHaan of `i = (i-1)%4;` would have been just fine, but he suffered a -1 for that because it was wrong for `unsigned char`.  The subtleties of integer of `unsigned char` promotion come into play in a way differently than the now `unsigned`.  Suggest reverting the edit.

Answer (score 4):

The operation you want to perform is fairly simple: if `i` is 0, set it to 3, otherwise decrement it.

Your code should express that operation as clearly as possible. The code in your question does that reasonably well.

You could also use the `%` remainder operator, but it *might* impose too much overhead if the cycle length isn't a power of 2 (as it happens to be in this case).

I'd be tempted to write the code a bit more tersely:

```
i = (i==0 ? 3 : i-1);
```

It's easy to get carried away and write code that looks like line noise (and code speed is *not* related to the number of characters in an expression), but in this case I think the conditional operator is clear enough.

Comment: Minor: "the `%` modulo operator" - C calls it the "remainder operator", though not much difference in the unsigned math world.

Answer (score 3):

Since you explicitly asked for bitwise operators, this:

```
i=(i-1) & 0x03;
```

should do the trick. Only works if the first number which you *don't* want to see is 2, 4, 8, 16, 32,...

Comment: I would kill the programmer who wrote that.

Comment: Still better then adding 3 when you really want to subtract 1 (as Khaelid is doing).

Answer (score 2):

Use modulo arithmetic

```
i = (i+3) % 4
```

Comment: This will never overflow because the mod keeps it less than 4

Comment: @m0skit0: How could it overflow?

Comment: @m0skit0 I just edited it to make that clear. Thanks for bringing it up

Comment: But this works only in the specific case for 3, right? If I want to start at, say, 5 instead (so 5,4,3,2,1,0,5,4,...) it breaks. Right?

Comment: @Søren Debois In the case of `N down to 0`, use `i = (i+N) % (N+1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Should be pretty simple:

```
i = (i+3)%4
```

Comment: This gave me 255 when `i` is an `unsigned char` set to 0. Changing `i` to an unsigned int gave me incorrect results in the general case.

Comment: @Khaelid The trouble is `-1` is an `int` and `i` is some unsigned type.  Operating on those 2 gives a signed or unsigned value depending on various things.  If all is done `unsigned`, it works fine.

Comment: You guys are correct, I changed it to be correct with unsigned.

Answer (score 0):

Why not something like this with nary a division or conditional branch in sight (excluding the `while`):

```
#include <limits.h>
...
unsigned int  cnt = UINT_MAX ;
unsigned char i   ;
while ( 1 )
{
  i = 0x00000003U & (cnt--) ;
  do_something_useful(i) ;
}
```

pretty sure you'll get tight code that simply loads a register with `UINT_MAX` and loops around stuffing `i` with the appropriate value.